# Equivalent of symbolic regression but for code instead of math expression

Tags: reference-request, evolutionary-algorithms, symbolic-ai, genetic-programming

I'm already well versed with Genetic/Memetic algorithms and similar algorithms. I know about Symbolic regression, where some dataset is fitted through a math expression evolution, but I'm wondering, is there any name for equivalent algorithm but for Code instead of Math expression?

I looked around using keyword such as "Programming regression" or "Code regression" or similar but did not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called **genetic programming**.

I've done a bit of research on the topic in the past. If you use Python, you could use [deap](https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/advanced/gp.html), which is quite easy to use. You may also be interested in [the PushGP approach](https://faculty.hampshire.edu/lspector/push.html). If yes, you could try [this library](https://github.com/erp12/pyshgp).

Comment: Yeah, I tried all of those already yesterday, but wanted to confirm if there was another name. Thank you.